# How do I pass the nid of the current node to the first step multistep modal form?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I am using the [ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) plumbing to create a nodal form. This is what the relevant part of my code now looks like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(&$build) {
  $nid = $build['body']['#object']->nid;

  // Set up ctools etc. to use modal omitted for brevity.

  $build['links']['popup']['#links']['mylink'] = array(
    'title' => 'show popup',
    'href' => 'mymodule/nojs/modals',
    'html' => TRUE,
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'ctools-use-modal', 
        'ctools-modal-mymodule-style',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The `nid` of the node this link will be attached to is known at this point. (See first line of function.)

However, my code need to be aware of the `nid` at each step in the modal form.

I think it possible to do this by stashing it in a session cookie, but I would like to avoid using cookies, if possible.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could always use a hidden form field to store the nid in.

Comment: @enzipher How do I get the access to the form object inside `hook_entity_view_alter`, which is where I have access to the `$nid`?  In the function I build the form object `$nid` is not available (unless it can be pulled from path, as suggested by Clive).

Comment: Good question.. Somehow I missed which hook you were in. Clive's answer is probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to change your path to incorporate the nid, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/%ctools_js/modals/%node'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 3),
    ...
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Change the path in the link

```
$build['links']['popup']['#links']['mylink'] = array(
  'title' => 'show popup',
  'href' => 'mymodule/nojs/modals/' . $nid,
  'html' => TRUE,
  'attributes' => array(
    'class' => array(
      'ctools-use-modal', 
      'ctools-modal-mymodule-style',
    ),
  ),
);
```

And in your callback:

```
function MYMODULE_callback($js, $node) {
  // $node is fully loaded, continue as normal...
}
```